# CSS - overriding an inherited text-decoration:line-through

Tags: css, inheritance, strikethrough

I've created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y7ZVp/) to demo the problem. I want the select box in the following to be normal text, and the rest to be struck out. The HTML is:

```
<div class="strike">
    This is struck out text
    <select>
        <option>but</option>
        <option>and</option>
    <select>
    this is struck out, too.
<div>
```

The CSS is:

```
div.strike {
    text-decoration: line-through
}
div.strike select,
div.strike option {
    text-decoration: none
}
```

The `select` box is still struck out, however.

If you try the following, you get blinking struck-out text!

```
div.strike select,
div.strike option {
    text-decoration: blink
}
```

How can I set the `select` box back to just normal text?

Thanks.

EDIT: I logged a [bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=786946) at Bugzilla.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/puKHb/ seems fine to me.. Unless I misunderstood your question?

Comment: I don't see your problem in your fiddle...what browser are you using?

Comment: @KyleSevenoaks  Yes, Chronial is right, I think. It works OK on Safari and Chrome. Who knew Firefox would strike out (pun intended)?

Comment: Haha good pun ;) I was using Chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try these http://jsfiddle.net/Y7ZVp/4/

its working fine.

else you can add your text on

tag and give `line-through` on `.strike p`

you can try any on them

Comment: Yes, you're right - it's working fine (even on Firefox) :) But I thought that `<s>` is deprecated...

Comment: then you can try another way ..wrap your text in any tag then give line-through

Comment: Yes, true, although in my real-world case it doesn't work, I'm afraid. As the blokes noted above, it seems to be a Firefox bug, but kudos for getting it to work on Firefox anyway :)

Comment: is your answer not close yet ? still faceing problem ?

Comment: Sorry, got distracted by the kids :)  Tried before but the 10 minutes wasn't up.